# Specific font and size of the footer (page number)

Tags: fonts, header-footer, fontsize, page-numbering, fancyhdr

Simple as it is but I can't find an answer. Working on a novel.

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside,openany]{book}
```

Want to use specific font for page numbers. Currently it's governed by Fancyhdr

```
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\sffamily\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\thepage}
```

The document is formatted in EB Garamond 9pt. So I want the page number to be also in EB Garamond of the same size. But with my current settings it is not. Though the size looks like it's 9 pt as I wanted. So how do I specify the font for the footer (page numbering) to be exactly EB Garamond?

Comment: Will `\fontfamily{mdugm}\selectfont` do it? And why `\sffamily` since this font seems to be serif.

Comment: Do you load fanctyhdr before or after you change the default font?

Comment: `\fontfamily{mdugm}\selectfont` changed the font but I am not sure to which? How do I know that it changed it to EB Garamond? And is EB Garamond a serif font? And I load fanctyhdr before I change the default font.

Comment: Fancyhdr uses the default font of the document for the headers/footers, so if your document is in 9pt EB Garamond, then `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}` should typeset your page numbers also in 9pt EB Garamond.

Comment: Can't believe that! My code was really overthought! You're right. `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: By the way, the `9pt` option for `book` doesn't work. The standard documentclasses have no `9pt` option. So unless you have included a package or some code to change that you will get 10pt as your default font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the whole problem was because the original code contained unnecessary lines. Correct it to `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}` and the footer will use the document's font and size!